# Custom ToolBar как сделать?

Tags: java, android

Нужно выполнить такую штуку. В шапке экрана должен быть логотип как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я это выполнил так, отключил `ActionBar` в разметке разделил `LinnearL` на части по весу и вот верхушка в которой стоит лого занимает 10% экрана в которой я как картинку поставил лого. Я новичок поэтому сделал так))

Теперь хочу переделать. Насколько я понял сейчас самый гибкий вью в этом плане это `ToolBar`. Вопрос вот в чем, нужно поставить в середину `ToolBar` лого, чтоб получилось как на скрине... Я не нашел ни одного примера в котором ставили бы изображение в `ToolBar` с возможностью регулировать положение этого изображение в нем...

**Кто работал с `ToolBar` подскажите можно ли такое сделать и если да то как?**

Comment: Toolbar это обычный ViewGroup добавте в него например FrameLayout, ну а дальше и так понятно )

Comment: Вы собираетесь использовать `Toolbar` еще и по прямому назначению -  навигация в приложении, меню и тп. или только эту картинку сверху надо. Если второй вариант, то использовать для этих целей `Toolbar` нет никакого смысла, у него другой юзкейс, Пусть тогда так и остается, как сейчас, вполне нормальное решение.

Comment: @pavlofff Нужно будет добавить еще `NavigationDrawer` , буду использовать по назначению, но по ТЗ нужно прицепить лого наверх...

Comment: Да и плюс к тому же мне кажется что тулбар будет лучше смотреться на разных экранах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Соглашаюсь, что:

> "Если второй вариант, то использовать для этих целей Toolbar нет
>   никакого смысла, у него другой юзкейс, Пусть тогда так и остается, как
>   сейчас, вполне нормальное решение."

Но если вам это надо сделать то можно например так:

***Главное активити:***

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar));
    }
}
```

***Разметка главного активити:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vitaliy.testtoolbar.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***И разметка для самого ToolBar:***(tool_bar.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_24dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

*Результат:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужно не забыть проверить, чтоб тема не содержала акшнбар

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**ToolBar - используется, как обычный ViewGroup. И я все же прислушался к совету, который дал вам "pavlofff" в комментариях к вопросу!**

Comment: Нужно будет добавить еще `NavigationDrawer` , буду использовать по назначению, но по ТЗ нужно прицепить лого наверх... Сейчас попробую ваш совет, если все получиться напишу как будет выглядеть. Да и плюс к тому же мне кажется что тулбар будет лучше смотреться на разных экранах

Comment: Да мне кажется, это то, что нужно

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, рад, что помог )))